# side-effects for `wye` combinators when using `halt` from scalaz-stream

Tags: scalaz, scalaz-stream

`filter` (which uses `halt` inside) terminates other branch even if it has some side-effects:

```
scala> val p = Process("1","2", "3")
scala> val p1 = p.filter(_ => true).map(_ + "p1").observe(io.stdOutLines)
scala> val p2 = p.filter(_ => false).map(_ + "p2").observe(io.stdOutLines)
scala> (p1 yip p2).run.run
1p1

scala> val p2 = p.filter(_ => true).map(_ + "p1").observe(io.stdOutLines)
scala> (p1 yip p2).run.run
1p1
1p2
2p1
2p2
3p1
3p2
```

Seems logical as there is no value to be returned to `yip` after that `filter`. But what about side-effects, specified with `observe`?

My current solution is to use `flatMap` to specify default value:

```
scala> val p1 = p.map(_ + "p1").flatMap(x => Process.emit(x).observe(io.stdOutLines))

scala> val p2 = p.map(_ + "p2").flatMap(x => Process.emit(""))

scala> (p1 yip p2).run.run
1p1
2p1
3p1
```

But maybe there is a way to use `filter`?

P.S. `merge` combinator executes side-effects for other branch (as it doesn't require value to be returned), but it doesn't wait for other branch if one halts (even if it has side-effects).

Comment: Not sure if I understand the issue? You would like to run p1 even when p2 terminates ?

Comment: exactly, as I still need p1 for side-effects. `filter` in any branch terminates both branches by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it should be just something like that:

```
in.map(emit).flatMap{ p =>
  val p1 = p.map(_ + "p1").filter(_ => true).observe(out)
  val p2 = p.map(_ + "p2").filter(_ => false).observe(out)
  p1 merge p2
}.run.run
```

It makes all side effects being in order as `filter` can't get more than one value (produced by emit)

Answer (score 0):

To run the effects even after p2 terminates there needs to be clear `default` behaviour. So there are probably these solutions:

1. define `p2` to supply default value after being terminated
2. use `either` wye to get left and rights if we don't really need tuples

perhaps the (1) is closer to question and code will looks like:

```
val p = Process("1","2", "3")
val p1 = p.filter(_ => true).map(_ + "p1").observe(io.stdOutLines)
val p2 = p.filter(_ => false).map(_ + "p2")
         .observe(io.stdOutLines).map(Some(_)) ++ emit(None).repeat
// alternativelly
// val p2 = p.map { v =>  if (pred(v)) right(v) else left(v) }
//          .observeO(o.stdOutLines).flatMap { _.toOption }
//          ++ emit(None).repeat             

(p1 yip p2).run.run
```

Comment: I believe `either` wye has the same problem as `merge` it will execute side-effects, but won't wait for them. Unfortunatelly same for the first option, just try `val p2 = p.map{x => Thread.sleep(1000);println("!" + x);x}.filter(_ => false).map(_ + "p2").observe(io.stdOutLines).map(Some(_)) ++ emit(None).repeat` and you'll see races between "2" and "3" messages. That's the reason I can't use `merge` combinator

Comment: My process is actually getting messages from one queue and publishing them to another one. And in both branches - it's the same destination queue, so I have to maintain correct order. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why you just cannot do then `q.dequeue.pipe(processor).to(q.enqueue)` ?

Comment: I have `.observe(q.enqueue)` in both branches instead of `observe(io.stdOutLines)`. Anyway I'm pretty happy with my `flatMap`, no big deal